# Some database content disappeared after WAMP reinstallation

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I screwed up the config files for Apache

I reinstalled(without any uninstall) the WAMP in same folder but instead of 2.4 I did 2.5, so WAMP failed gloriously afterward.

I can not access WAMP anymore, so I can not backup my DBs from PHPMyAdmin (any hint about how to do backup in this senario will be helpful)

I copy the whole /wamp folder content (after screwed up the install).

I installed the 2.4 version Now WAMP running All DBs are still listed there But when I accesss two of the WP sites, they ask me to create a new site title, but not allow me to set username (says"User(s) already exists.").

Now I went back PHPmyAdmin and  found the db for that WP site is EMPTY

I wonder how can I retrieve the good database information stored in that original /wamp folder backup, somehow, transfer into the new one, so that the db table that is EMPTY will populate with the original data again?

Thank You

Comment: Are these 2 WP databases MYISAM or INNODB?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Both of them are INNODB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the safest way to recover is to:

Stop WAMPServer.

Copy the old MySQL folders to the new install of WAMPServer

So thats

```
copy \wamp_backup\bin\mysql\mysql(old version) to \wamp\bin\mysql\
```

Start WAMPServer again.

Now in the menu

```
Wampserver -> MySQL -> Version
```

you should see you old mysql version and the new one that came with the new install as well.

Switch to the old version by clicking on the old version number on that menu.

Wamp shoud now switch from the new MySQL to the old. Wait for WAMPServer to go green again.

Check the Mysql error log, to see if anything unpleasant has happened, if not,

You can then use phpmyadmin, or whatever tool you are used to to backup your missing databases.

Then switch back to the new version of MySQL and restore the databases to this version of mysql.

I hope this goes smoothly, it should.

Comment: I had all the files from old version. Copy and paste work perfectly without going through the following steps but very useful to know! Thank you very much!